# how change my menu on submenu

Tags: plugins, php

i have one options in my menu and i wont change it on submenu but i have only fails...

```
// Call Terms_and_conditions_menu is function which load plugin menu
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'Terms_and_conditions_menu' );

// Add to WordPress admin menu
if( !function_exists("Terms_and_conditions_menu") )
{
function Terms_and_conditions_menu(){

  $page_title = 'WordPress Extra Post Info';
  $menu_title = 'Terms And Conditions';
  $capability = 'manage_options';
  $menu_slug  = 'terms-post-info';
  $function   = 'terms_post_info_page';
  $icon_url   = 'dashicons-media-code';
  $position   = 4;

  add_menu_page( $page_title,
                 $menu_title,
                 $capability,
                 $menu_slug,
                 $function,
                 $icon_url,
                 $position );
```

Tag my menu where i want add it is: wpjb-config

Answer (score 0):

You can add a sub menu like below.

```
  // Call Terms_and_conditions_menu is function which load plugin menu
    add_action( 'admin_menu', 'Terms_and_conditions_menu' );

    // Add to WordPress admin menu
    if( !function_exists("Terms_and_conditions_menu") )
    {
    function Terms_and_conditions_menu(){

      $page_title = 'WordPress Extra Post Info';
      $menu_title = 'Terms And Conditions';
      $capability = 'manage_options';
      $menu_slug  = 'terms-post-info';
      $function   = 'terms_post_info_page';
      $icon_url   = 'dashicons-media-code';
      $position   = 4;

      add_menu_page( $page_title,
                     $menu_title,
                     $capability,
                     $menu_slug,
                     $function,
                     $icon_url,
                     $position );

    add_submenu_page( $menu_slug,'sub page', 'menu title',$capability, 'my-secondary-slug');

    function my-secondary-slug(){

      echo 'Page text';
    }
```